# Giuga and Carmichael numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

If $p$ is both Giuga and Carmichael number

then its known that

$1^{p-1}+2^{p-1}+3^{p-1}+\cdots+(p-1)^{p-1} \equiv -1\pmod{p}$

is it true that

if $p$ is both Giuga and Carmichael number then

$1^{p-1}+2^{p-1}+3^{p-1}+\cdots+(r-1)^{p-1} \equiv (r-1)\pmod{p}$
where  $2\le r\le p-2$

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: So your sum should run from 1 to $k-1$, not to $k$, right?

Comment: i don't know the range . i have doubt whether it runs from 0 to $k-1$ or 0 to $p-1$.

Comment: Crossposted on MSE http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/663086/giuga-and-carmichael-numbers

Comment: yeah i had not get solution there, thats why i asked here.

Comment: You asked here only 3 hours after asking there, and without giving any sort of indication of this. Please do not do this, as it can cause duplication of effort.

Comment: @GerryMyerson sry , The summation upper limit is k-1 .

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft sorry for doing like this . I will not repeat it again.

Comment: @GerryMyerson yeah . upper limit is $k-1$ . Is the final result is always the upper limit ?

Comment: Where did the first statement was proved?

Comment: If $r$ is not coprime to Carmichael $p$ your equality doesn't hold.

Comment: Your new version does not make sense as the $k$ is not really doing anything there.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft i am confused . Its p.

Comment: In total it seems like you did not really change anything with the last two edits, other than notation.

Comment: yeah . To simplify .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $n$ is Carmichael, then $a^{n-1}\equiv1\pmod n$ for all $a$ with $\gcd(a,n)=1$. If $\gcd(a,n)\ne1$, then it is clearly impossible to have $a^{n-1}\equiv1\pmod n$. So, let $n$ be Carmichael, let $r$ be the smallest divisor of $n$ (other than 1); then it is impossible to have $1^{n-1}+2^{n-1}+\cdots+r^{n-1}\equiv r\pmod n$, since the first $r-1$ terms are 1 (mod $n$) and the last term isn't.

Comment: Its also giuga number , any difference ?

Comment: @hanu If it always fails for Carmichael numbers, then it does not help to restrict to a subset of the Carmichael numbers.

Comment: The only difference it makes is that if there aren't any numbers that are both Carmichael and Giuga (and that's what Giuga's conjecture asserts, isn't it?), then the premise is vacuous, and the conclusion follows vacuously.